# ${\rm Hom}(\textbf{G},\textbf{Ab})$ is the category of $G$-modules

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, category-theory, modules

This question is related to an exercise in Bosch's Algebraic Geometry (Chap. 4.5, Ex. 2)

Fix a group $G$ and write $\textbf{G}$ for the one-point category with morphisms given by the group $G$ and $\textbf{Ab}$ for the category of abelian groups. The claim is that ${\rm Hom}(\textbf{G},\textbf{Ab})$ is the category of $G$ - modules, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}$-modules with a $G$ - action.

For clarification, given categories $C_1,C_2$, ${\rm Hom}(C_1,C_2)$ is the category of all covariant functors $C_1\rightarrow C_2$, where a morphism $\phi:F\rightarrow G$ between two such functors is a functorial morphism.

These are my thoughts so far: A functor $F:\textbf{G}\rightarrow \textbf{Ab}$ defines an abelian group $F(G)$. I want to define and action $g\cdot x$ for $g\in G$ and $x\in F(G)$ induced by $F$, but I don't know how. What I can define is an action of ${\rm Hom}_G(G,G)$ on $F(G)$ by $f\cdot x:= F(f)(x)$ for a morphism $f:G\rightarrow G$ and $x\in F(G)$. But this is not what I want.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't call $G$ both the group and the unique object of $\bf G$: a nameless label like $*$ is better, especially because it is absolutely irrelevant "what" is $*$.

Call $X=F*$.

A morphism $g \in {\bf G}(*,*)$ is an element of $G$. By the definition of $\bf G$, $g$ is an endomorphism of $*$. Actually, an *auto* morphism.

Every such $g$ induces an endofunction $F(g) : F* \to F*$, that has to be invertible because $g$ was invertible ($g^{-1}$ is its inverse). This defines a function $a : G \to {\rm Aut}(X)$. The fact that $F$ was a functor implies that this function is a group homomorphism, so $G$ acts on $X$. Actually, $F$ is a functor *if and only if* $a$ is an action.

Comment: I used the same notation as in the book by Bosch for $G$ $\textbf{G}$. Let me rephrase how I understand for post: For every $g \in G$ you consider the associated group - homomorphism $\phi_g(a) = gag^{-1}$, which is an automorphism, right? (Because otherwise I don't know what you mean by "A morphism $g\in G$ is an element of $g$". Then we get an $G$ - action on $X = F(G)$ by $g\cdot a := F(\phi_g)(a)$. So every functor $F:\textbf{G}\rightarrow \textbf{Ab}$ induces an $G$ - action on $F(G)$.

Comment: But I have two question: First, don't we need some sort of uniqueness? I.e. something like "every functor induces a unique $G$ - action". Secondly, do we need some kind of inverse statement like "every $G$ - module $N$ induces a functor $F:\textbf{G}\rightarrow \textbf{Ab}$ such the associated $G$ - actions agree?

Comment: I made an edit, try to re-read the answer! And yes, every $G$-module induces a functor, functoriality *is* the condition a certain function is an action, and viceversa :-)

Comment: What do you mean by "a morphism $g\in \boldsymbol{G}(*,*)$"? I think my trouble is due to notational conventons, maybe you could clear that up for me? I tried to make sense of $g\in G$ inducing an automorphism $\phi_g:G\rightarrow G$ by $a\mapsto gag^{-1}$ and defining an action via $F(\phi_g)$ on $F(G)$.

Comment: $\bf G$ has just one object, the nameless point $*$; elements of the group are endomorphisms of $*$; group axioms (more precisely, monoid axioms) are exactly the category axioms. So $\bf G$ is a category if and only if $G$ is a monoid, and a groupoid if and only if $G$ is a group (every element of $G$ is invertible iff every morphism of $\bf G$ is invertible). Functoriality of $F$ means that the image of $g$ under $F$ must be an isomorphism. An isomorphism $F* \to F*$, i.e. a bijection of $X$.